# Table cell width increases with addition of row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following table:

```
<table border="1" class="mmrTable" id="mmrdisplayTable">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width: 160px; font-weight: bold;" id="mmrdisplayTD">Running Projects:</td>
        <td id="mmrdisplayTD">This month's running project</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width: 160px; font-weight: bold;" id="mmrdisplayTD">Main Orders:</td>
        <td id="mmrdisplayTD">This month's main orders</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width: 160px; font-weight: bold;" id="mmrdisplayTD">Main Opportunities:</td>
        <td id="mmrdisplayTD">This month's main opportunities</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width: 160px; font-weight: bold;" id="mmrdisplayTD">Comments/Summary:</td>
        <td id="mmrdisplayTD">no comments</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

As soon as I add a row above all rows the width of the first column of all the other rows changes from 160 to something else. Can someone tell me why? and help me reduce it to 160?

[image]

The code for the row that I add is:

```
<td colspan="2" class="headDisplay">Month: May|
                        Year: 2014| Submitted by: ibrahim nadir|
                        Submission Date: 2014-05-22| Submitting department: IT
                    </td>
```

The CSS is:

```
#mmrdisplayTable {
                    width: 100%;
                }

.headDisplay{
                background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3C68AE;
                border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                font-weight: bold;
                height: 20px;    
            padding: 2px 10px;
        }

 #mmrdisplayTD{
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding:5px;
        }
```

Any suggestions and help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Looks OK here: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/KEK6D/

Comment: Thanks but what did you change? Could u tell me please? Add your answer so i can update the question as solved.

Comment: Nothing. I simply used the code you posted.

Comment: Maybe i can put the screenshot of both firefox and google chrome so you can see the with of columns changes after adding row at the top.

Comment: Take a look now please

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty easy solution.

Just add this to your css.

```
#mmrdisplayTable {
    max-width: 320px;
}

#mmrdisplayTD {
    min-width: 160px;
}
```

so your css looks like this:

```
#mmrdisplayTable {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 320px;
}
headDisplay {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3C68AE;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}
#mmrdisplayTD {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding:5px;
    min-width: 160px;
}
```

max-width in #mmrdisplayTable is just 160px * the amount of td's.

See the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KEK6D/1/)** i made.

Comment: sorry, i didn't read it all correct the first time, let me check it again.